# Testing for compliance with and casting to RawRepresentable protocol

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have some generic code that allows me to read and write various types to the defaults system, e.g. value getters and setters:

```
var value : T {
    
    get {
        if T.self == Int.self {
            return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: storageKey) as! T
        } else if T.self == Double.self {
            return UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: storageKey) as! T
        } else if T.self == Float.self {
            return UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: storageKey) as! T
        } else if T.self == Bool.self {
            return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: storageKey) as! T
        } else if T.self == String.self {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: storageKey) as! T
        } else {
            return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: self.storageKey) as! T
        }
    }
    
    set(value) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: storageKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Now I want to add my own enum types to this mechanism by making them `RawRepresentable<Int>`, e.g.

```
enum Direction : Int, RawRepresentable {
    case left = 0
    case right = 1
}
```

Unfortunately, I can neither find the magic incantation to test whether `T` conforms to the `RawRepresentable` protocol, nor can I cast `T` to the `RawRepresentable` protocol, because no matter what I try, I always end up with a `Protocol 'RawRepresentable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

I have tried every `where` and `as` incantation until I have started doubting that it can be done at all!?

I'm in Swift 5 and the goal is to create new instance by invoking `CustomType(rawValue:)` and  getting the Int value by calling `myValue.rawValue`.

Comment: Why not simply **one** line `return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: self.storageKey) as! T` rather than all those ugly type checks? On the other hand you should check for `nil` and for non-PropertLlist compilant types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vadian said, all those type checks can be replaced be a single call to `UserDefaults.standard.object()` and conditional casting. Also the type of the `value` property needs to be an optional to handle the case where the property is not set (or not of the correct type):

```
struct DefaultKey<T> {
    let storageKey: String
    
    var value: T? {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: storageKey) as? T
        }
        nonmutating set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: storageKey)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can define a constrained extension method where you specialize the computed property for the case of `RawRepresentable` types:

```
extension DefaultKey where T: RawRepresentable {
    var value: T? {
        get {
            if let rawValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: storageKey) as? T.RawValue {
                return T(rawValue: rawValue)
            }
            return nil
        }
        nonmutating set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue?.rawValue, forKey: storageKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
enum Direction : Int {
    case left = 0
    case right = 1
}

let key1 = DefaultKey<Int>(storageKey: "foo")
key1.value = 123
let key2 = DefaultKey<Direction>(storageKey: "bar")
key2.value = .right

print(key1.value as Any) // Optional(123)
print(key2.value as Any) // Optional(Direction.right)
```

Note that this can still crash if used with non-property-list types. To be on the safe side, you would have to restrict the extensions to types which are known to be user defaults storable (integers, floats, strings, ...):

```
protocol UserDefaultsStorable {}
extension Int: UserDefaultsStorable {}
extension Float: UserDefaultsStorable {}
// ...

struct DefaultKey<T> {
        let storageKey: String
}

extension DefaultKey where T: UserDefaultsStorable { .. }

extension DefaultKey where T: RawRepresentable, T.RawValue: UserDefaultsStorable { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of trying to specialize the type constraints via an extension. I need Objective-C interoperability so the code snippet is in a class and the initializer provides a default value, so I know it's of the right type and non-null and I'm avoiding returning an optional. I got everything to compile now (hurray!), but it's not consistently calling the specialized methods!? The actual class/protocol morass is far more complicated, so I need to figure out what's going on next week.. thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll mark the question as answered, but I have posted a follow-up question on dynamic dispatch and generics..